# Could not install `discord.py` due to EnvironmentError

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py

[Windows 10] [Python 3.8.3] The remainder of the error:  `Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: path/to/ca-bundle.crt`
I have tried `pip3 install -U discord.py` `py -3 -m pip3 install -U discord.py` `pip3 install discord.py` but I can't seen to get it to install.

Comment: It might have to do with the directory you are trying to install it to. Try installing it to C:\Windows\system32

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some kind of 3rd party program like PyCharm for python, write this on the terminal:

```
python -m pip install discord.py
```

In IDLE, follow these steps:

```
 1. cd C:\Users\[Your Username]\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38[On Me]\Scripts
 2. python -m pip install discord.py
```

Hope this helps. Have a good day!

*Edit: Your `Python\Python38` might be different, I think you could check it by pressing `"WINDOWS + R"`, and writing `%appdata%` on the box. After that by scrolling down a bit you should find `Python`.

Comment: I am still getting the `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: path/to/ca-bundle.crt` error.

Comment: Did you put python in PATH? If you didn't, that might be why it's not working. Watch this: https://youtu.be/Y2q_b4ugPWk.